# Advanced iPad programming

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ipad, ios

I finished learning the *Big Nerd Ranch Guide to iPhone* programming but now I need a more advanced book for advanced concepts particularly for iPad App Dev.

Could you please recommend one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Pragmatic iPad book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/sfipad/ipad-programming) is coming out soon. The main author, Daniel Steinberg, is a good writer. You can download some sample chapters from it too.

There's not all that much extra to know. Mostly you need to learn about split-view controllers and popovers. If you absolutely must have a book now, the [Wrox: Beginning iPad](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470641657) seems pretty good, but you'll go over a lot of info you've already learned

Apress has one for iPhone converts too: [Beginning iPad Development for iPhone Developers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430230215). Jack Nutting (very good writer, author of the Apress Cocoa book) is the second author.

Comment: Thanks.  I will buy that one.  I just think that I need more information about specially Web Services and also like you say the UI aspects

Comment: The APress book is now on my wish list. :-)

Comment: Recommendations for learning resources [are off-topic for stackoverflow.com Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, this information [could _maybe_ be ok as part of a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/997587).